# How to produce messages to different Kafka topics and schema registries from the same producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to produce messages to different kafka topics from the same producer in my Java application.

This is how I create my producer and send a message to the topics.

```
@Bean
public Producer producer() {
    Properties config = sdpProperties();
    config.setProperty("schema.registry.url", "");
    config.setProperty("client.id", "1");   ...
    return new Producer(config);
}
producer.send(topic1, genericRecord, datasetId1);
producer.send(topic2, genericRecord, datasetId2);
```

However, these two different topics have different schema.registry.urls. Through research, I saw that you can set more than one registry url in the config but when I try to follow this, it only validates against the second url. Messages to topic2 are produced correctly but messages to topic1 are not. Messages to both topics are only validated against url2 instead of validated topic1 against url1 and topic2 against url2.

```
 config.setProperty("schema.registry.url", "ur1,url2");
```

How can I use the same producer to send messages to these two different topics even though they have different schema.registry.urls? Am I setting this config incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

[Ideally, you shouldn't have multiple registries](https://www.confluent.io/blog/17-ways-to-mess-up-self-managed-schema-registry/).

But if you are aware of the architectural design behind that decision, then you must create two unique producers with different registry urls. The comma separation is for load balancing against one "registry cluster", not a loop over multiple, unique registries

Comment: ahh I wasn't aware of that but isn't it inefficient to have more than one producer?

Comment: If they have different properties, then there's no other option

Comment: What's the best way to create different producers in the same application?

Comment: In Spring, create a new `KafkaTemplate` object that takes a different factory and config map

Comment: Is there a way I can just create two new Producer beans?

Comment: The KafkaTemplate class from spring-kafka is a wrapper around a producer object